# C++ How to set a severity filter on a Boost Global Logger

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I've been trying for days now to create a Boost Global Logger for use throughout the application **but I can't seem to get the severity level set in the Global Logger**.

**IMPORTANT:**

**Look below for Andrey's answer...it's labeled as step (a) and (b) but I'm still not getting it right!**

---

Right out of the Boost Documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html)

> ...it would be more convenient to have one or several global loggers in
>   order to easily access them in every place when needed. In this regard
>   std::cout is a good example of such a logger.
>
> The library provides a way to declare global loggers that can be
>   accessed pretty much like std::cout. In fact, this feature can be used
>   with any logger, including user-defined ones. Having declared a global
>   logger, one can be sure to have a thread-safe access to this logger
>   instance from any place of the application code. The library also
>   guarantees that a global logger instance will be unique even across
>   module boundaries. This allows employing logging even in header-only
>   components that may get compiled into different modules.
>
> ---
>
> Regardless of the macro you used to declare the logger, you can
>   acquire the logger instance with the static get function of the logger
>   tag:

```
src::severity_logger_mt< >& lg = my_logger::get();
```

I found out from the Boost Logger guru, Andrey, that my problem is **the severity type mismatch**.

> You have instantiated severity_logger_mt with default template
>   parameters, so the severity level attribute has type int. Your enum
>   values are converted to int and sent to the logging core. You have not
>   set up any sinks, so by default the default sink is used. The sink
>   attempts to extract severity level attribute value from log records,
>   but fails to do that because it expects the severity level to be of
>   type boost::log::trivial::severity_level. After that failure the sink
>   falls back to boost::log::trivial::severity_level::info severity.
>
> If you want to use your enum for severity levels you have to:

**------------------------------------ (  Now, here is the ANSWER !!!!  ) ---------------------------------------**

> **(a) specify it in the logger template parameters and**
>
> **(b) set up a sink with a formatter that is aware of your enum.**

But I can't figure out how to do this, because even after trying to follow his instructions the severity level looks like the sink is still falling back to the boost::log::trivial::severity_level::info severity.  Can anyone help me figure out how to get the severity set correctly in my global logger?  Here is the code:

**HEADER**

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>

enum severity_level
{
    normal,
    warning,
    error,
    critical
};

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(logger, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt< severity_level >)
```

**CPP**

```
#include "GlobalLogger.h"

#include <boost/log/expressions/formatters/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;

bool onlyWarnings(const boost::log::attribute_value_set& set)
{
    return set["Severity"].extract<severity_level>() > 0;
}

void severity_and_message(const boost::log::record_view &view, boost::log::formatting_ostream &os)
{
    os << view.attribute_values()["Severity"].extract<severity_level>() << ": " <<
    view.attribute_values()["Message"].extract<std::string>();
}

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(logger, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt< severity_level >)
{
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt< severity_level > logger;

    // add a text sink
    typedef sinks::asynchronous_sink<sinks::text_ostream_backend> text_sink;
    boost::shared_ptr<text_sink> sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();

    // add "console" output stream to our sink
    boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> stream{&std::clog, boost::null_deleter{}};
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(stream);

    // specify the format of the log message
    sink->set_formatter(&severity_and_message);

    // just log messages with severity >= SEVERITY_THRESHOLD are written
    sink->set_filter(&onlyWarnings);

    // "register" our sink
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

    logging::add_common_attributes();

    return logger;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "GlobalLogger.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<  severity_level >& lg = logger::get();
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, severity_level::normal) << "note";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, severity_level::warning) << "warning";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, severity_level::critical) << "critical";

    return 0;
}
```

I found a better example [62.10. A macro to define a global logger](http://theboostcpplibraries.com) and a working version in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068278/1735836).  But the working example does not use the get() method.  So, after declaring the BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER, I was able to access log::get() **but I still can't get it to recognize the severity**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found Andrey, the Boost Log expert.  To help others in the future, I am posting a link to our [Sourceforge discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/boost-log/discussion/710021/thread/1fb9819c/?limit=25).  After much banging my head on my monitor, it took his explanaition and revisiting the working version in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068278/1735836).  But I finally got it working!  YAY!!!

Comment: Can you please post your complete working solution anywhere? More specifically I am looking for a solution where all the logging configuration is in a ini file.  My question is posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172457/log-file-is-not-getting-created

Comment: @BKS, I haven't looked at that code since I got it working.  I no longer work for that company.  Take a look at the Sourceforge discussion and the SO question posted as links above.  I'll try to get something working for you but it might take a few days.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There was a helpful tip on that question that resolved the issue.